# AJAX отправка формы "теряет данные" из пары полей

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Весь проект на C# MVC на вьюхе к полю прикручен DatetimaPicker от xdsoft.
Мне необходимо отправлять данные на сервер когда меняется поле даты.
код на странице:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.Hidden("StartDateTime")
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    /*window.Error = function (errorMsg) { alert(errorMsg); }*/


    $.datetimepicker.setLocale('ru');

    $('#Start').datetimepicker({
        dayOfWeekStart: 1,
        lang: 'ru',
        format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
        startDate: '@DateTime.Now',
        step: 30,
        value: '@DateTime.Now'
    });
    $('#Start').change(function () {
        $('#StartDateTime').attr('value', $('#Start').val());
    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var FormData = $('form').serializeArray(); 
    $('#Start').focusout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("TrainerTime","Schedules")',
            type: "POST",
            data: FormData
        })
    })
</script>
```

Так вот когда это ajax скрипт - то поле Start всегда равно Default, а поле StartDateTime равно null, даже если во время отладки вижу как поле меняется на правильную дату:

```html
<input name="StartDateTime" id="StartDateTime" type="hidden" value="20.02.2016 12:30">
```

При этом, если я делаю отправку формы по кнопке, то данные отправляются корректные. Подскажите пожалуйста, чего я не понимаю?

Comment: Почему `serializeArray`, а не [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

Comment: Посмотрите какие запросы делаются браузером в обоих случаях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно причина в том, что переменная `FormData` у вас формируется до изменений значений полей формы. Записывать переменную правильно нужно в момент события `focusout`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Start').focusout(function () {
        var FormData = $('form').serializeArray(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("TrainerTime","Schedules")',
            type: "POST",
            data: FormData
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы не просто ответили на вопрос, но и добавили понимания! Всё работает!